# Failure during project creation using 'djangocms' command

Tags: python, django, pip, django-cms

- Django CMS 3.4.1
- Django 1.10.2
- pip modules: http://pastebin.com/vJWvZVfA
- pip 8.1.2
- Python 2.7.12
- OS: Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03

I'm new to Django CMS, Django, and Python. My previous CMS experience has been with WordPress and I'm try to try out Django CMS as an alternative to WordPress, but am getting an error that I can not seem to figure out. I have updated the pip modules and installed others as suggested in threads on StackOverflow, but to no avail.

I followed the [tutorial the instructions](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/install.htm), with the exception of the `djangocms` command, which is incorrect in the tutorial. (It's missing the -w flag.)

EDIT: As requested, here is the output with the `--verbose` flag added:

```
(env)[ec2-user@(redacted) tutorial-project]$ djangocms -d postgres://(redacted) -e no --permissions yes -l "en-CA, en-US, en, fr-CA, fr-FR" -p . --starting-page yes --verbose --utc mysite
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
Package install command: install django-cms<3.5 djangocms-admin-style>=1.2,<1.3 django-treebeard>=4.0,<5.0 psycopg2 djangocms-text-ckeditor>=3.2.1 djangocms-link>=1.8 djangocms-style>=1.7 djangocms-googlemap>=0.5 djangocms-snippet>=1.9 djangocms-video>=2.0 djangocms-column>=1.6 easy_thumbnails django-filer>=1.2 cmsplugin-filer>=1.1 Django<1.9 pytz django-classy-tags>=0.7 html5lib>=0.999999,<0.99999999 Pillow>=3.0 django-sekizai>=0.9 django-select2<5.0six
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-duWZSN/psycopg2/
The installation has failed.


*****************************************************************

Check documentation at https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io

*****************************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 33, in execute
    verbose=config_data.verbose
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 91, in requirements
    output = subprocess.check_output(['pip'] + args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'pip', u'install', u'django-cms<3.5', u'djangocms-admin-style>=1.2,<1.3', u'django-treebeard>=4.0,<5.0', u'psycopg2', u'djangocms-text-ckeditor>=3.2.1', u'djangocms-link>=1.8', u'djangocms-style>=1.7', u'djangocms-googlemap>=0.5', u'djangocms-snippet>=1.9', u'djangocms-video>=2.0', u'djangocms-column>=1.6', u'easy_thumbnails', u'django-filer>=1.2', u'cmsplugin-filer>=1.1', u'Django<1.9', u'pytz', u'django-classy-tags>=0.7', u'html5lib>=0.999999,<0.99999999', u'Pillow>=3.0', u'django-sekizai>=0.9', u'django-select2<5.0six']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

EDIT 2: (moved to answer)

EDIT 3:

After solving the first part, another error remains. I'll include it in this post since it still falls under the topic of the title:

```
Creating the project
Project creation command: /home/ec2-user/env/bin/python2.7 /home/ec2-user/env/bin/django-admin.py startproject mysite /home/ec2-user/tutorial-project
Database setup commands: /home/ec2-user/env/bin/python2.7 -W ignore manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 118, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 158, in get_connection_params
    "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
The installation has failed.


*****************************************************************

Check documentation at https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io

*****************************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 41, in execute
    django.setup_database(config_data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/django/__init__.py", line 388, in setup_database
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/ec2-user/env/bin/python2.7', u'-W', u'ignore', u'manage.py', u'migrate']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I'm going to guess that the problem lies in the message:

`settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
The installation has failed.`

I'm using PostgreSQL, so I assume that the error is caused by the schema not being provided in the command argument. There was nothing in the guide that I saw indicating how to provide it, so I'll have to search some more.

Comment: Hello @PaulC, can you create a virtual environment in exactly the same way as the one you used for cms, but instead of installing the djangocms-installer, please run pip install psycopg2. I'm trying to assess if the issue is isolated to the installation of that one package.

Comment: Hi @Paulo. Just saw your comment. I've updated the post with additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So that last error, you get it from running "djangocms -d postgres://(redacted) -e no --permissions yes -l "en-CA, en-US, en, fr-CA, fr-FR" -p . --starting-page yes --verbose --utc mysite"?

Comment: @Paulo: Yes, but it was because I was missing the database name from the (redacted) part of my database URL. Installation now succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells me absolutely nothing.  It only tells me that Django tried to use pip to install something and for whatever reason it failed.  In order to figure out what went wrong, try enabling verbose mode (python -v).  If that gives the same output, or that isn't an option because you're using a program that calls Python (which it sounds like you are), let me know and prepare to go into the source code.  Trust me, I have taken many a dive into source code for Python utilities, and as long as you don't do anything stupid (like delete a file) it's pretty hard to mess anything up.  Even if you do you can always reinstall Django (or make a backup first).  Don't worry about messing up your computer.  You'd have to work hard to make Django do that!

Comment: Should this be a comment on the question?

Comment: It should be a comment instead of an answer, yes.

Answer (score 0):

## Original error

The non-verbose error message indicates the error in a cryptic way, and using --verbose provides a more understandable message.

I was missing one required module (psycopg2) and four others were versions which were too new (easy_thumbnails, Django, html5lib, django-select2).

I uninstalled the four modules and then reinstalled them using the version requirement in the command. e.g. pip install 'Django<1.10'.

psycopg2 required extra steps, as I got an error message when trying to install it indicating that it could not find pg_config. Another SO answer advised that I just had to install postgresql-devel. After I did that, (sudo yum install postgresql-devel), I also uninstalled postgresql8-libs, as postgresql-devel came with a newer version. I didn't do it before since yum indicated a PHP dependency, and I wasn't sure if it would cause problems if I did.

## Second error

Pretty simple. I was missing the /NAME component of the database URL (postgres://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/NAME).